# Recommendations for preventing RequireJS from interfering with legacy code

Tags: requirejs, legacy-code

I'm developing a 'widget', for lack of a better word, that will be loaded in many different sites that I don't control.

We're using RequireJS to keep things easy, but this has the side effect of breaking A LOT of sites that don't already use/support it.

The be clear - we don't control the sites, and the cause is that many of the sites existing libraries are loading into RequireJS instead of globally, and the code on these sites expects them to be loaded globally.

The only practical solution I can think of so far is to rename RequireJS' require() and define() (and perhaps others), then edit every library we rely on (using sed, of course) to load using the 'new' functions.

Has anyone else dealt with this? Is there a better method I'm missing?

- Michael

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this, here's what I ended up doing...

There isn't a good solution for this at the moment as:

1) All libraries that load into RequireJS need define() to exist in their scope at execution time

and

2) There isn't any mechanism for asynchronously loading scripts that would allow define to be defined (pun not intended) and undefined before/after execution, aside from eval(), and that's just not a good option.

This means that, it's not really possible to have some type of scoped RequireJS without it possibly interfering with other scripts on-page that CAN use RequireJS, but are intended to load globally on that particular site.

So... here's the hacky solution I did...

Instead of loading the JS libraries myself, I bundled them on the fly, along with RequireJS, and wrapped in an immediately executing function.

The reason for doing this on-the-fly, is that some site specific data is necessary for the program to function, and it saves an HTTP request to obtain it (at the expense of a larger file download).

This allowed me to:

1) Use libraries that need to run under RequireJS (or similar) to work property

2) Avoid cluttering up the global namespace for stuff like jQuery

3) Avoid editing library source (eg. changing define() to my_special_define() or similar)

I hope this helps someone if they're trying to do the same thing as me :)